# Can't achieve desired output on c++ multithreading program

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, g++, openmp

It seems no matter what I try results always come out in order.

I'm using visual studio code on ubuntu. I've looked at multiple tutorials (for example this one: [video environment config](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waAwl6_Kd_0), used all the add ons like in the video) however the results seem to still be coming out very much in order.
Here is my main file
All 100 numbers that are being printed are in order:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Makefile file:
(as can be seen I've added the openmp flag)

```
CXX       := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb -fopenmp

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB     := lib

LIBRARIES   :=
EXECUTABLE  := main


all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
    clear
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -L$(LIB) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    -rm $(BIN)/*
```

I've tried running

```
make clean
make
```

to ensure the flag I've added is visible.

I also have a different example program that doesn't behave like I'd want it to. It's also using OpenMp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

void execute(const std::string& name) {
    std::cout << name << ": one" << std::endl;
    std::cout << name << ": two" << std::endl;
    std::cout << name << ": three" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> names = {"First", "Second"};
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    threads.reserve(names.size());

    std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(threads),
        [](const std::string& name) {
            return std::thread(execute, name);
        }
    );

    for (std::thread& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    std::cout << "Program finished execution" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know I've written a successfully parallel program in C# using slmost same tools if that helps.

Comment: How do you set the number of threads in the first case? Live demo of out-of-order output: https://godbolt.org/z/5cre8ojGs. If you don't use the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable, and you don't specify the number of threads in the code, then some system-defined value is used, which may be 1.

Comment: Your second program is not using OpenMP and it's kinda muddying the waters here. The first program might be missing `num_threads` like Daniel noted, or it may be just a normal behaviour - these threads have very little work to do, it's not unreasonable that they would happen to run sequentially.

Comment: Parallel output is always a bad idea because the operating system buffering gets in the way. You can not tell anything about parallelism from screen output.

Comment: in your second program add  `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);`  after first print in`execute(...)` and look at result again.

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen thank you for the tip. I have confirmed that everything is set up properly now :-)

Comment: @DanielLangr very helpful, i guess my system-defined value for the number of threads indeed is 1